# Testing with Nose. Why am I getting "ImportError: No module named bin.app"

Tags: python

I'm currently on the last exercise (EX52) of Learn Python The Hard Way and I'm using Nose to test out the code (the exercise is to expand Nose testing to test out more of the code).

This is my file structure

```
bin
    app.py
gothonweb
    __init__.py
    map.py
sessions
tests
    map_tests.py
    app_tests.py
```

The sample code tests out the map.py file using the map_tests.py code.

```
from nose.tools import *
from gothonweb.map import *

def test_room():
    central_corridor = Room("Central Corridor" ...
```

So I thought I'd expand this by creating a second test file, called app_tests.py that tested the app.py file. It contains this code

```
from nose.tools import *
from bin.app import *

def test():
    pass
```

When I run nosetests I get this error: **ImportError: No module named bin.app**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your directory structure you can see that `bin` is not a python package. It is a directory that contains a python module named `app` as referenced by `app.py`. Python packages have an `__init__.py` file inside of folders. I could explain in more detail but it would probably be better to post a link for you to reference.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

Comment: I realized I could not possibly do the topic justice in a stackoverflow answer so a good reference site was the better choice!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a `__init__.py` in your `bin` directory, it's just a directory, not a package. Since it's not a package, you can't look into the package to find the `bin` module.

From your parent directory, do

```
touch bin/__init__.py
```

on Mac/Linux, or

```
type NUL>bin\__init__.py
```

on Windows